# Using of nltk for chunking arabic text

Tags: python, nltk, chunking

I have a project about chunking of Arabic text 
I want to know if it is possible to use NLTK to extract the chunks NP, VP, PP of arabic Text and how I can use an Arabic corpus.
Please any one help me!

Comment: can I generate my own Part Of Speach? or I can use a tagged text...

Answer (score 1):

It's far from perfect (largely because the linguistic properties of Arabic are significantly different from those of English), but [a computer science student developed an Arabic language analysis toolkit in 2011](http://www.nada.kth.se/utbildning/grukth/exjobb/rapportlistor/2011/rapporter11/shouhani_rabiee_hajder_11133.pdf) that looks promising. He developed "an integrated solution consisting of a part-of-speech tagger and a morphological analyser. The toolkit was trained on classical Arabic and tested on a sample text of modern standard Arabic." I would think a limitation of this tool would be that the training set was classical while the test set was MSA.

The paper is a great start because it addresses existing tools and their relative successes (and shortcomings). I also highly recommend [this 2010 paper](http://www.morganclaypool.com/doi/abs/10.2200/S00277ED1V01Y201008HLT010) which looks like an outstanding reference. It is [also available as a book in print or electronic format](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1598297953).

Also, as a personal note, I would love to see a native speaker who is NLP-savvy use [Google ta3reeb](http://www.google.com/intl/ar/inputtools/cloud/try/) (available as a [Java open source utility](http://code.google.com/p/ta3reeb/)) to develop better tools and libraries. Just some of my thoughts, my actual experience with Arabic NLP is very limited. There are a variety of companies that have developed search solutions that apply Arabic NLP principles as well, although much of their work is likely proprietary (for instance, I am aware that [Basis Technology](http://www.basistech.com/) has [worked with this](http://www.basistech.com/base-linguistics/arabic/) fairly extensively; I am not affiliated with Basis in any way nor have I ever been).